# Background-image doesn't appear in span inside a button

Tags: css, button, background-image, html

This should be easy for you I hope :)
I am trying to make three buttons with repeating background images. I use two `<button>` and a link `<a>`. It works with the link but not with the buttons - the side images (the rounded corners) don't appear. Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Task 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="task1.css">
</head>

<body>
<button class="blue-btn"><span id="left">&nbsp;</span>OK<span id="right">&nbsp;</span></button><br/>
<button class="blue-btn"><span id="left">&nbsp;</span>Cancel<span id="right">&nbsp;</span></button><br/>
<a href="#" class="blue-btn"><span id="left">&nbsp;</span>View More Information<span id="right">&nbsp;</span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.blue-btn{
    background: url('button-repeat.png') repeat-x;
    border:0;
    height:55px;
    font: 14px/44px Myriad-Pro, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#left{
    display:block;
    background: url('button-left.png') no-repeat;
    height:55px;
    width:24px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-24px;
}
#right{
    display:block;
    background: url('button-right.png') no-repeat;
    height:55px;
    width:24px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:-24px;
}
```

Comment: IDs are **unique**. You cannot use `id="left"` or `id="right"` more than once on a page. You should use `classes` for this: `class="left"` and `class="right"`.

Comment: Along with @JamesDonnelly post, once you switch from ID's to classes in HTML, you reference those classes in your CSS with a period " . "  So for example: .right {} or .left {}

Comment: Oh, yes - I forgot about that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that. You might have to give up on using `<button>`s and style a regular element (probably `<a>`, `<span>` or `<div>`) to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try styling your button without the use of spans and instead use multiple background images and multiple positions.

```
.button {
background-image: url(), url();
background-position: left top, right top;
}
```

*Note that IE 8 and IE9 are [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with some position magic. Make the blue_btn position:relative and the left and right part should be position:absolute. Also don't use id's for styling, add some meaningfull class names to the button parts.

```
.blue-btn{
  position: relative;
}

.btn-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 10px;
}
.btn-left {      
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 10px;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xinix/3kbzc/1/)